# Inserting large amount of data into android sqlite database?

Tags: android, database, excel, sqlite, import

I have a large amount of data i want to import into one sqlite database.
4column and 150 rows. Currently the data is in a excel spreadsheet.

How can i import it into my android application?

```
    String SQL = "create table " + TABLE + "( " 
        + BaseColumns._ID
        + " integer primary key, " 
        + Column1+ " text, "
        + Column2+ " text, "
        + Column3+ " text, " 
        + Column4+ " text);";
        db.execSQL(SQL);        

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(DBAdapter.Column1,  "HP");
        values.put(DBAdapter.Column2,  "qw");
        values.put(DBAdapter.Column3,  "5280");
        values.put(DBAdapter.Column4,  "345, 546");
        db.insert(DBAdapter.TABLE, null, values);

        ContentValues values2 = new ContentValues();
        values2.put(DBAdapter.Column1,  "P");
        values2.put(DBAdapter.Column2,  "other");
        values2.put(DBAdapter.Column3,  "other");
        values2.put(DBAdapter.Column4,  "345");

}
```

This is how i have inserted two rows into my DB, but i dont want to have to do this for 150?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could store the information on a CSV file, then read the file and store each row in sqlite.

Answer (score 0):

You can load database on your desktop using any of db console, add it to resources and replace db file created by DbHelper with your own file.
If you use Motodev it will be much easier.