# Linking android app and database?

Tags: android

I want to create and store a database for android.
I am creating a football quiz game. I want to create a repository of questions and answers,and correct answer. I dont want it to be online but stored on the phone.My intention is to use math.random to create a random number to access the question. I have only got the UI up now. If i need to use mySQL or something what would be a good resource to learn that?
TIA

Comment: Use SQLite for using database in mobile.

Comment: You also can use db4o, because i think you will not have millions of questions. Its easy to use (but slower then sqllite). db4o is a object-relational-database.

Comment: Or you could just google it before posting to stackoverflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to understand the Android SQLite Database.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/package-summary.html

To create and maintain the database and more on the same:
http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidSQLite/article.html
http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/

The random number can be a primary id.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SQLite database which is inbuilt in android. For storing bulk data [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10840117/load-large-amount-of-data-to-db-android) post will help. Get the random number.