# To insert large amount of data in android SQLite Database

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I am new in Android Development.

Currently, working with SQLite Database in Android.

My problem is that I have a large amount of data which I have to store in SQLite Database in Android.

There are 2 tables: One having 14927 rows and the other one has 9903 rows.

Currently the database in sql. And I have copy these data in excel sheet but don't understand how can I import these data in SQLite Database.

I go through the following link:

[Inserting large amount of data into android sqlite database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6465696/inserting-large-amount-of-data-into-android-sqlite-database)

Here, the solution is posted regarding CSV File. But want to know other ways of doing this.

Please let me know what is the best way to import such a large data in Android.

Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you tried saving excel file as csv?

Answer (score 2):

**Do Like This**

```
SQLiteDatabase sd;
    sd.beginTransaction();


        for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++) {
            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put(DBAdapter.Column1,  "HP");
            values.put(DBAdapter.Column2,  "qw");
            values.put(DBAdapter.Column3,  "5280");
            values.put(DBAdapter.Column4,  "345, 546");
            sd.insert(DBAdapter.TABLE, null, values);
            sd.insertWithOnConflict(tableName, null, values, SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_IGNORE);

        }

    sd.setTransactionSuccessful();
    sd.endTransaction();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 SQLiteDatabase db = Your_DATABASE;
 db.beginTransaction();
 db.openDatabase(); 

for (int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++) 
{
    String sql = ( "INSERT INTO " + Table_NAME 
                                  + "(" + COLUMN_1 + "," 
                                        + COLUMN_2 + ","  
                                        + COLUMN_3 + "," 
                                        + COLUMN_4 + "," 
                                  + ") values (?,?,?,?)");

    SQLiteStatement insert = db.compileStatement(sql);
}

db.setTransactionSuccessful();
db.endTransaction();
db.closeDatabase();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [DatabaseUtils.InsertHelper](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/DatabaseUtils.InsertHelper.html). In this [article](http://www.outofwhatbox.com/blog/2010/12/android-using-databaseutils-inserthelper-for-faster-insertions-into-sqlite-database/) you will find an example of how to use it and other ways to speed up insertions. The example is as follows:

```
import android.database.DatabaseUtils.InsertHelper;
//...
private class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // Create a single InsertHelper to handle this set of insertions.
        InsertHelper ih = new InsertHelper(db, "TableName");

        // Get the numeric indexes for each of the columns that we're updating
        final int greekColumn = ih.getColumnIndex("Greek");
        final int ionicColumn = ih.getColumnIndex("Ionic");
        //...
        final int romanColumn = ih.getColumnIndex("Roman");

        try {
            while (moreRowsToInsert) {
                // ... Create the data for this row (not shown) ...

                // Get the InsertHelper ready to insert a single row
                ih.prepareForInsert();

                // Add the data for each column
                ih.bind(greekColumn, greekData);
                ih.bind(ionicColumn, ionicData);
                //...
                ih.bind(romanColumn, romanData);

                // Insert the row into the database.
                ih.execute();
            }
        }
        finally {
            ih.close(); 
        }
    }
//...
}
```